# How do I say this Tu form command/ Imperative tense?

Tags: traducción, conjugación, imperativo

How do I say "Water the flowers" as an informal singular positive command (tu form)?

Google Translate just gives me the noun for water ("agua las flores). I plan to google "to water" next and then use the *tu* form. I forget how to do positive *tu* form commands, as it's been so long since High School.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Indeed, robots don't translate well, because they don't understand that you mean `water` the verb ("regar") and not the noun ("agua"). You can check the conjugations of a verb in the [DRAE online dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VhX4gyn). So basically, this is a question that can be answered with a dictionary (or is not about imperative, but about other possible translations of "water"). Please, visit [tour], [help] and [ask]. Thanks and welcome again. The better your question, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As Diego says in his comment. The word "water" here is used as verb, hence the translation is "regar".
The common way to translate "water the flowers" would be "riega las flores".

Comment: Could you give OP a resource they could use in future to look up this sort of thing?  That would strengthen your answer.